# Add a fixed static row in a angular Mat Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, angular-material-table

I have a dynamic table using mat-table where i render the columns from the data object.

```
 <table #myTable mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">...
```

I render the columns

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>id</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
</ng-container>
...

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

I want to add a static row in the end of the table data where i want to show some sum values from the mat-table columns.

I can provide this row name in the array like:
private displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'sum'];
Where id and other column names are present in my object and mapped accordingly but how can i add this static sum row ?

Comment: i don't get your point. you want to add row? or column ? you already have **sum** column in your table !

Comment: can you show what output you required ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate sum of table columns and show in footer using Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55580753/how-to-calculate-sum-of-table-columns-and-show-in-footer-using-angular)

Comment: Yes that and this one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-footer?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html . So basicly i need to add mat-footer-cell to each element.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a footer to the bottom
either you can make it stick to bottom like this [Sticky Footer](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nnlkeexbgov?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-footer-example.ts)

or you can add non sticky footer [Non Sticky footer with added text](https://stackblitz.com/angular/amakmvbedpq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-multiple-header-footer-example.html)